# Consider a ternary channel with the following channel matrix:

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

\begin{bmatrix}
1-\alpha & 3\alpha/4 & \alpha/4\\
\alpha/4 & 1-\alpha & 3\alpha/4\\
3\alpha/4 & \alpha/4 & 1-\alpha\\
\end{bmatrix}

I was told that the probability of error of this channel can not be $\alpha/4 $ or $3\alpha/4$.
How do I know this? How can i find the probability of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an input symbol $x$. The probability that the output symbol differs from $x$ is $\alpha$ (regardless of the choice of $x$).

Therefore, regardless of the input distribution, the probability of error will be $\alpha$. As you see, you can have $\alpha = \alpha/4  = 3\alpha/4$ when $\alpha=0$.